# C# and Powershell sharing memory

Tags: c#

I have a Powershell script being executed from a C# program. Both use a C# dll with static memory. When the Powershell script is executed, it has access to the same data that the C# program set. Additionally, anything the Powershell script writes to the dll is available the next time the script is called.

I want them to be completely separate so that the Powershell script runs in its own environment and memory space.

Here is my code:

```
using ( var _powerShell = PowerShell.Create() )
            {
                try
                {
                    _powerShell.Runspace = null;
                    _powerShell.RunspacePool = null;
                    _powerShell.AddScript($"{scriptFile} {args}");
                    _powerShell.Invoke();
                }
                catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    _powerShell.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

I am guessing I need to create a new Powershell session or something? I'm stuck.

Comment: `Process.Start`.

Comment: And `finally` block is redundant

Comment: `_powerShell.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null);`

Comment: @PetSerAl this throws an InvalidRunspaceStateException

Comment: @usr1 You need to open runspace before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer thanks to PetSerAI:

```
using ( _powerShell = PowerShell.Create() )
{
    try
    {
        var run = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null);
        run.Open();
        _powerShell.Runspace = run;
        _powerShell.AddScript($"{scriptFile} {args}");
        _powerShell.Invoke();
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

update:
So there is a bug in the above code...
the newly crated runspace is not released until the end of the program. I had this code being called multiple times, which resulted in a hundred background powershell instances. Here is the fix:

```
using ( var run = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null) )
{
    run.Open();
    using ( _powerShell = PowerShell.Create() )
    {
        try
        {
            _powerShell.Runspace = run;
            _powerShell.AddScript($"{scriptFile} {args}");
            _powerShell.Invoke();
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```